# Where to define the menu items event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, menu, architecture

I have a DataGridView on a WinForm.  When the user right-click on the grid, I am showing a popup menu. There are 3 kinds of popup menu according to where the right-click has been done:

1. on a row that is defined as readonly
2. on a row that can be edited
3. on any other place in the grid (rowindex is -1)

I created a new classes to manage the popup menus generation.

```
public class GridPopupMenuFactory
{
    public ContextMenu GetMenu(int rowIndex, bool isReadOnlyRow)
    {
        BaseMenu _menu = null;

        switch (rowIndex)
        {
            case -1:
                _menu = new GeneralMenu();
                break;
            default:
                if (isReadOnlyRow)
                {
                    _menu = new ReadonlyRowMenu();
                }
                else
                {
                    _menu = new EditableRowMenu();
                }
                break;
        }

        return _menu.Menu;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseMenu
{
    protected ContextMenu _menu;
    public ContextMenu Menu
    {
        get
        {
            if (_menu.MenuItems.Count == 0)
            {
                GenerateMenu();
            }
            return _menu;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void GenerateMenu();
}

public class GeneralMenu : BaseMenu
{
    protected override void GenerateMenu()
    {
        var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Sort"));
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Print"));            

        _menu = contextMenu;
    }
}

public class ReadonlyRowMenu : BaseMenu
{
    protected override void GenerateMenu()
    {
        var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("View"));            

        _menu = contextMenu;
    }
}

public class EditableRowMenu : BaseMenu
{
    protected override void GenerateMenu()
    {
        var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Add"));
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Edit"));
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Delete"));

        _menu = contextMenu;
    }
}

// Winform
private void shipmentDetailsDataGridView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var rowIndex = shipmentDetailsDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
            var popupMenu = GridPopupMenu.GetMenu(rowIndex, false);  // 2nd parameter can be true, TODO

            popupMenu.Show(shipmentDetailsDataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }
    }
```

My question is where is the correct place to define the event handler for each one of the menu items?

Update:
After clicking on the menu item, the whole operation is done on the DataGridView itself.
For example, clicking on add, will open a temp form with all the required field and then this information will be added as a new row in the DataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should looks like this:

```
public class GeneralMenu : BaseMenu {
    protected override void GenerateMenu() {
        var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Sort", OnSort));
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Print", OnPrint));
        _menu = contextMenu;
    }
    void OnSort(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var gridView = GetSourceControl<DataGridView>(sender);
        if(gridView != null) {
            // do sort
        }
    }
    void OnPrint(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var gridView = GetSourceControl<DataGridView>(sender);
        if(gridView != null) {
            // do print
        }
    }
    static TControl GetSourceControl<TControl>(object sender) where TControl : Control {
        var menu = ((MenuItem)sender).GetContextMenu();
        return (menu != null) ? menu.SourceControl as TControl : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that all the datagridview control is on the Window form. Should it be passed as parameter to the  constructor?

Comment: It depends on how you use the resulting menu. Unfortunately the exact wayt of the GridPopupMenuFactory usage is not clear from your question. Please update it if possible...

Comment: I've updated my answer with `GetSourceControl` method. Please, review it - i believe, it give you all needed information to implement your task. p.s. Move this method into the base class for real usage...

Comment: I didn't knew about SourceControl, it is even better than passing the DataGridView as parameter to the factory and then trickle it down to the other classes.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of respective classes.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Each class contain multiple menu items and then multiple event handlers.